# how do i make a negative number red in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-apex

I have a display field called 'exceeding amount' which shows the difference between two fields (invoice number - MCT) when the 'exceeding amount' is negative I want the number to be red. This is all in a form view not a report

Answer (score 3):

Use a Dynamic Action to set the style or class that is triggered by a change in value. Something like this would work. Adapt to your requirements.

[image]

Make sure they fire on initialization as well.

[image]

Comment: Are you able to demonstrate the issue on apex.oracle.com? And if possible, include temporary workspace credentials.

Comment: I download and install the 11g don't know if u will be able to access it via that. its on my work domain

Comment: What version of APEX are you on? And define "not working". Are there any error messages? And did you try with a simple use case like I have above?

Comment: am using apex 18.1 , no am not getting any error messages and yes I did exactly what u have above

Comment: What a nice demo!

Comment: very nice demo.. am flowing it to a 'T' but still no luck

Comment: Thanks! That's bizzare. Any sign of JavaScript errors? When logged in to the App Builder, the developer toolbar (usually at the bottom of the page) has an indicator on the toolbar's left corner. It's red with a white bell. That tells you that a JS error occurred. I should have also asked... which browser are you using?

Comment: One or more errors have occurred since the page loaded. Open the Browser's JavaScript console to see the errors. am using IE and I tried Chrome

Comment: What are the error messages in the JavaScript console?

Comment: http://download.microsoft.com/download/B/9/F/B9FF9327-7A72-4165-BF91-9B7EEB6C579B/DeviceList.json. I downloaded it but how do I add it to the application

Comment: Use the developer console in [Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/). Copy and paste the error message in the comments here.

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: apex.item(...).getvalue is not a function
    at Object.triggeringExpression (f?p=106:4:1245465771140:::175)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (desktop_all.min.js:23)
    at Function.each (desktop_all.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (desktop_all.min.js:2)
    at Object.da.actions (desktop_all.min.js:23)
    at Object.<anonymous> (desktop_all.min.js:23)
    at Function.each (desktop_all.min.js:2)
    at r.fn.init.each (desktop_all.min.js:2)
    at Object.da.init (desktop_all.min.js:23)
    at f?p=106:4:1245465771140:::200

Comment: The function to get the value of the page item should be "getValue" and not "getvalue". The "v" should be capitalized.

Comment: Thank u it worked , who know something so simple will throw off the result

Comment: Glad to hear! Yeah, it's often the little things.